# How to can I make a select box that is selected with href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box in my code:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

    <option value="?type=1">
        Filter here
    </option>
    <option value="?type=1">
        Change Management
    </option>
    <option value="?type=2">
        Projects
    </option>
</select>
```

It is working fine, but I want to make the selected box in the selected status. If I selected change management, the page will refresh so the selected item changes to the filter by. How can I overcome that?

#### Pagination code

```
{%if objects.has_next or objects.has_previous%}
    {% load i18n %}
    <div>
        <ul class="pagination">
            {% if objects.has_previous %}
                <li><a href="?{{ objects.previous_page_number.querystring }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>{% trans "previous" %}</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <!-- <li>{% trans "previous" %}</li> -->
            {% endif %}
            {% for page in objects.pages %}
                {% if page %}
                    {% ifequal page objects.number %}
                        <li><a>{{ page }}</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="?{{ page.querystring }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
                    {% endifequal %}
                {% else %}
                    ...
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if objects.has_next %}
                <li><a href="?{{ objects.next_page_number.querystring }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>{% trans "next" %}</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <!-- <li>{% trans "next" %}</li> -->
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: how can i keep the selected index there after refreshing it

Comment: are ue using any server side script

Comment: Ok few mins I will provide you in javascript

Comment: Get the query string from the url in dom ready, then use $(".form-control).val("query string");

Comment: @AnoopJoshi This should go answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with this code...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var path = window.location.href;

        if (path.indexOf('?') !== -1)
        {
            var path1 = path.split("?");
            var value = "?" + path1[1];
            document.getElementById('select').value = value;
        }
    });

</script>

<select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" id="select">
<option value="?type=1">Filter here</option>
    <option value="?type=2">Change Management</option>
    <option value="?type=3">Projects</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think chrome browser have only that issue

Comment: Even tough its a browser issue its an issue right So If possible I will check it if you provide the code

Comment: I have wrote the code to select the select box based on href value in the browser I think when Pagination is adding the url is changing some thing like this '?type=2&page=3' So its not displaying..

Comment: yes, before pagination url look like this agent?type=1, after pagination url is chnaged to agent?page=2

Comment: then How You are..sending the type(i.e type=1) to select the select box if you are not sending it will not select

Comment: while changing the dropdown list i have created options then its value is an href. as same as yur mentioned code. after selecing one there i have set it a pagination, sothe the selection has gone. i want to keep the selected option there

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the html and javascript code how you are setting pagination

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the query string in the DOM ready. Then set the option like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var queryString = "?type=3"; // Replace this with the code for getting query string
    $(".form-control").val(queryString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript code:

```
var selectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0],
options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (location.href.indexOf(options[i].value) > -1) {
        selectBox.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```